# Mysterious Error 3355 - SQL machine not available every day at the same time

Tags: 2007, error, sql-server, events

One my users reports that he cannot access our Sharepoint MOSS 2007 installation at midnight each night.

I look in the Event Viewer and **every day** this error appears at 12:25:20 am:

I'm confused by the fact that the timestamps inside the Event Description range from 11:55 PM to 12:08 AM the following day. So how come the event time is 12:25 AM?

And further, where else should I look for information about this error?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Windows SharePoint Services 3
Event Category: Database 
Event ID:   3355
Date:       4/26/2012
Time:       12:25:20 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   AMWEB01
Description:
Cannot connect to SQL Server. amsql01 not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
2012-04-25T23:55:16.027: Starting
2012-04-25T23:55:16.043: dbo.NameValuePair_German_PhoneBook_CI_AS_CI is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-25T23:55:16.047: Rebuilding
2012-04-25T23:55:16.077: Done
2012-04-25T23:55:16.077: dbo.NameValuePair_German_PhoneBook_CI_AS_NoListId is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-25T23:55:16.077: Rebuilding
2012-04-25T23:55:16.077: Done
2012-04-25T23:55:16.080: dbo.NameValuePair_German_PhoneBook_CI_AS_MatchUserData is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-25T23:55:16.080: Rebuilding
2012-04-25T23:55:16.080: Done

.. more of the same...
2012-04-25T23:55:43.470: dbo.WelcomeNames_PK is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-25T23:55:43.470: Rebuilding
2012-04-25T23:55:43.480: Done
2012-04-25T23:55:43.493: dbo.TimerLock_PK is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-25T23:55:43.493: Rebuilding
2012-04-25T23:55:43.503: Done
2012-04-25T23:55:43.503: dbo.AllUserData_Url is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-25T23:55:43.503: Rebuilding
2012-04-26T00:04:18.297: Done
2012-04-26T00:04:18.297: dbo.AllUserData_PK is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-26T00:04:18.297: Rebuilding
2012-04-26T00:08:19.550: Done
2012-04-26T00:08:19.573: dbo.HT_Setting_PK is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-26T00:08:19.573: Rebuilding
2012-04-26T00:08:19.633: Done
2012-04-26T00:08:19.633: dbo.Workflow_PK is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-26T00:08:19.633: Rebuilding
2012-04-26T00:08:20.613: Done
more of the same
2012-04-26T00:08:23.937: dbo.NameValuePair_Arabic_CI_AS_NoListId is now being rebuilt.
2012-04-26T00:08:23.937: Rebuilding
2012-04-26T00:08:23.937: Done

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: What does the event log on the database server tell? I'd imagine that's the cause of the problem. Do the cleaning staff vacum the server room at that time and take the plug from the database server?

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it I would say check in SQL Server. This probably has to do with http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943345 defragmentating databases or rebuilding indexing. Could well that this was setup as a maintenance plan so check under there. Maybe something in there also takes the database offline.